# How does warped space actually look (visually)?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, visualization

Recently, I was reading about space warping due to extreme gravity and at speeds approaching c, but in books, they always show space in 2D and depth to show space distortion. I was wondering how exactly warped space look in actual?

Comment: your visualization would require you to imagine a fourth dimension, which is pretty difficult to imagine directly (some people claim to be able to do it). But for most of us, the analogy (and later generalization) of reducing the dimension of space to 2 and the warping to a third spatial dimension is the best we have.

Comment: Have you seen the movie *Interstellar*? The space distortion due to gravity is represented fairly accurately in this movie: Kip Thorne, who was the Feynman professor of theoretical physics at Caltech, acted as science advisor for the animated visualizations.

Comment: @brucesmitherson: But why do we need an extra dimension to depict space distortion ? While it is shown in most of the illustration, is there any proof (mathematical and practical ?) that space distortion creates an extra dimension ? (I'm just curious about physics with a very little formal knowledge about it, so sorry if it sounds childish.) Johannes: Yes, I've watched that movie. While most of the scenes and effects are based on actual equations (I recently read  this book, "science of interstellar" by Prof. Thorne. Genius indeed!), I can hardly recollect any scene about space distortion.

Comment: @dastaan no, you do not need an extra dimension to depict space distortion. However, and this is just my own opinion, that it is perhaps the easiest or simplest way to depict it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you travel through the warped spacetime, you would not notice much difference. This is because any spacetime regions you are likely to ever encounter look exactly the same as flat spacetime locally. This is great news for us because it means we'd always be able to assume that propelling ourselves forward will actually make us go forward and not to the side or something weird like that.

As a distant observer, we can actually see what warped space looks like. A phenomenon called [gravitational lensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) allows us to see the warping of spacetime as light passes by objects of large mass. Take a look at the picture below. That ring around the star is the light from a galaxy behind the star that has passed through warped spacetime.

[image]

Practised observers can actually see a few more examples of lensing in that picture (I can see 5 others, but I'm not an astronomer. How many do other people see?), but you get the idea. Pretty cool, eh?

Understandably, you may feel that this visualization does not give you an intuitive understanding about how things should behave in warped spacetime. That is why you often see the 2D simplification; it's easier to get the point across. But if you want a visual image of how gravity actually warps/curves spacetime, you'll find nothing better (at least, nothing I can think of) than a nice picture of an Einstein ring, like the one above.

<sub>Picture taken from Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: I was justing thinking about posting that image myself when your answer appeared.

Comment: Nice picture, but I wouldn't say it shows what curved space looks like. Gravitational lensing is a result of the curvature of space, like every gravitational effect, but this picture wouldn't look very different in flat space in which light is gravitationally bent, or if this would be a picture of emitted massive particles under the influence of Newtonian gravity.

Comment: @doetoe Newtonian gravity predicts that light would bend only half as much as it actually does, so the image would be slightly different. But as for the image itself, it is the best *visual* representation of warped space I can think of. If you can think of a better visual image of gravity-warped space, post it as an answer and let me know, I'll be the first to upvote it.

Comment: I guess that for any visual representation it is ultimately impossible to distinguish between curvature of space or bending of light rays. Of course what's nice of your example is that it is an *actual* image. I don't know if I can think of an example that is obviously a result of curvature rather than an optical effect in flat space (much less an actual image).

Comment: @doetoe That's exactly what I was thinking when I wrote this answer

Answer (score 3):

When we visualize a Riemannian manifold from outside, abstractly, as a part of ordinary space but with a different metric, like in the disk model of the hyperbolic plane, we get very nice images, but it looks very different from how it would look to a creature living inside of it.

[image: hyperbolic plane]

When you are inside, it doesn't look all that distorted, because you, and light rays, etc, all get warped in the same way. While walking toward the boundary in the hyperbolic disk model, you would just get smaller with every step. You would notice some things however, like parallel lines that move away from each other, triangles whose angles don't add up to $\pi$, etc.

The following is an image from *inside* hyperbolic space, made long ago by [the geometry center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lTig.gif), showing a tessellation of space with regular dodecahedra, which obviously is impossible in Euclidean space.

[image: Hyperbolic tessellation with regular tetrahedra]

As Johannes mentioned in a comment, the movie Interstellar has some pretty accurate and high quality graphics of gravitationally warped space, like this image of a black hole with its accretion disk.

[image: Black hole with accretion disk]

Note that the disk essentially lies in a plane, light from the central part cannot escape, but light escaping initially away from us may bend into our direction, so we see the disk essentially everywhere around the black hole. However, you don't directly see that you are in curved space, you just see that light is bent by gravity, and qualitatively it doesn't look different from how it would look in flat space in which light was bent by gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Space-time is founded on the idea that mass/energy do not change, but that space, that which contains all things, changes.  Consequently the concept of time is reflective of this change in space.

In other words, the speed of C is constant, and consequently so is mass.  The only thing that is relative is the changing of space and our idea of time.

"Seeing" this is as easy as looking around your home or office.  The very reality of change is space-time at work.

Comment: and how does that constitute a visual example of the warping of spacetime under relativity?

Comment: "Time", "space", "electromagnetism/mass",  " gravity",  are all part of life.  Just because we cannot observe readly the distortion of space and time here in our everyday affairs shouldn't mean that such a phenomenon such as the warping of space doesn't occur right here and now. it just means it's on the quantum level.

Comment: I maintain that still doesn't count as a visual example or description. Also, you seem to be speculating and basing your statements on personal philosophical musings rather than actual scientific expertise. This reads like some keywords have been included haphazardly.

Comment: I would agree. I will have to work a little harder on not just giving my philosophical opinion. Cheers